# Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target

Tags: android, android-studio

383/5000
I have an app that gives me compilation errors when I change it to release mode to upload it to the play store

I've tried analyzing-inspecting code
and I do not have any error.

I have also tried the compilation sugestion in the build build gradle and it does not give an error, but when I try to install the apk it gives me an error: "the APK failed to install. Error: Could not stop error string"

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.abort(LintGradleExecution.java:199)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.runLint(LintGradleExecution.java:263)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.lintSingleVariant(LintGradleExecution.java:359)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:38)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintPerVariantTask.lint(LintPerVariantTask.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 249):

1. You can right click on a folder or a file and use [Analyze > Inspect Code](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections) menu to manually run inspections.
   The results appear in the **Inspection Results** window. This way you can view and fix the real issues.
2. You can still view them from **app\build\reports\lint-results-release-fatal.html** file without using aforementioned manual inspection menu.
3. Although it's not recommended you can also suppress the lint warnings by adding below code into your **build.gradle** as Android Studio suggests.
   But keep in mind that this will not fix any real issues.

> ```
> android {
>     lintOptions {
>         checkReleaseBuilds false
>         // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>         // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>         abortOnError false
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Concur. It's amazing that even the latest Android Studio doesn't have a link to this after failing a Build due to lint, it simply shows a code snippet to DISABLE the errors.... !!!?

Comment: @BjornW be sure they will fix it in the future. Just give them some time, you can see the only tip of the iceberg of the work, fixes, and improvements they do in each release. They have to catch up with all Google's new APIs every year and keep improving the IDE. Actually, the Android Studio currently is one of the best IDEs out there.

Comment: Nothing against you @Kirill, but this aged liked milk. How many years does it take to fix this simple lint rule?

Comment: There is no `app\build\reports\` folder in my Android Studio, maybe they changed the path in Arctic Fox 2020.3.1?

Comment: Where is the "Analyze" button???

Answer (score 112):

You can find out details in your app path

```
 /YOUR_APPLICATION/app/build/reports/
```

[image]

in this folder, there is a HTML document that describes the error.

For more information, you can visit the page that i find a solution.

https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-find-cause-of-lint-error-while.html

Comment: This is the correct solution. Analyze > Inspect Code generates too many entries to find the actual culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the solution...it took me 10hrs to go one by one correcting the lint warning and finally by using your solution,. I got the exact reason behind the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no `app\build\reports\` folder in my Android Studio, maybe they changed the path in Arctic Fox 2020.3.1?

Comment: @rubo77 I also use 2020.3.1 and I still found the files.

Comment: @Arda Maybe you use Windows? I use Linux

Comment: Actual solution +1

Comment: If you don't see the files, they are here: `app/build/intermediates/lint_vital_partial_results/release/out`

Answer (score 82):

Here I have written an article on all possible [solutions to resolve Lint found fatal errors issue](https://handyopinion.com/lint-found-fatal-errors-while-assembling-a-release-target-android/).

Generally, you can resolve it in the following way:

Android studio shows all build errors in `html` & `xml` file present at the following link. Just open that file in your browser, check the error and fix it.

```
/YOUR_APPLICATION/app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.html
```

[image]

**Sample Error**

[image]

Comment: Great!! I think this is the **Perfect Way** to resolve it.

Comment: this answer is really helpful for me, thank you @Asad

Comment: There is no `app\build\reports\` folder in my Android Studio, maybe they changed the path in Arctic Fox 2020.3.1?

Answer (score 26):

This works for me

```
lintOptions { 
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Add this code into the build.gradle file within android {} section

Comment: Your answer is the same as one other answer.

Comment: it is not recommended, its better to find the error and fix it using the Analyze > Inspect Code

Comment: when you don't have time solution

Answer (score 9):

For me, the results file `lint-definite-release.xml` was located at `app/build/intermediates/lint_vital_partial_results/release/out`. I'm using Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you defined all the translations in all the string.xml files in your application.

Answer (score 5):

For me i checked the errors in the xml and html files in /APPLICATION/app/build/reports
Then i fixed all i could fix and for the rest i suppressed them by adding to my build.gradle the code below:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

This prevented android studio from aborting the build because of the remaining errors

Answer (score 5):

I faced the similiar issue and followed this way `Analyze > Inspect Code`. In my case it was the xml issues.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to build.gradle(Module: AppName)

below

```
android {
```

these lines

```
lintOptions{
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

above these lines

```
compileSdkVersion 31
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

}

Comment: Lint is likely failing for a reason, I would not recommend simply force ignoring the check like this. A better solution is to check the lint report as in @Lukas Niessen answer

Answer (score 4):

## 2024 Solution

The lint report is now located at: `myproject\app\build\intermediates\lint_vital_intermediate_text_report\release`

Answer (score 2):

After a while I find solution for my problem. Just check for differences between strings.xml(for different languages - if you have)

Answer (score 0):

as I see you are trying to have a bundle or any kind of version edition of your newly edited app, but here you have to pay attention to the minimumsdk and target sdk and some other settings in your app which may differ from the last android studio and play store standards so you have to edit them and if needed change them, but these kind of error are located in a file in the below log or report folder
it is html base and try to see it in a browser
the file is in this directory in your project:
app\build\reports
try to open it by a browser, it will help you and press what is preventing you from generating a bundle or app with a signature encrypted.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and followed this way to find the error and fix it. Analyze > Inspect Code. After that I found that the current `targetSdkVersion` was not supported. So I increased `targetSdkVersion` in the default config and that is how it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are plenty of answers given in this thread already, this is for those who want to know the issue. This error generally pops up because of XML/Layout/Resource file errors.
To solve this just recheck your layouts by either manually or mentioned methods in the above-given answers
I'm sure you'll find the root of cause...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in generate Apk  process . this showing errors process is improved in new version of gradle .I updated my gradle version to the last version then generated it again .it Showed Fatal Error in my Xml codes in best way.

Answer (score 0):

For me I found the error mentioned in this path `app\build\intermediates\lint_vital_intermediate_text_report\release\lint-results-release.txt`

noting that changing Ture to false in the below code is only a work around but will not solve the real problem and you might face troubles in production.

```
android {
lintOptions {
heckReleaseBuilds true          
            abortOnError true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Meet this problem today, My Android Studio says `lintOptions` is deprecated, try this new format.

```
lint {
  abortOnError = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to add the code below to your app-level build.gradle

```
  android {
      lint {
            baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
        }
    }
```

Then switch to the project view in Android Studio IDE
[image]

You could see the lint file under the app directory after building the project.
[image]

Open the file and you will see the issues below,
[image]

Copy the issue location -> fix the issues -> delete the file and rebuild your project.

Delete the lint file to avoid past history lint errors.

Tada!

Answer (score -1):

`File > Invalid Caches/Restart` has fixed the issue for me.
I am just getting started with the Android but I thought to try this before trying what's mentioned above and it worked.