# Why does Android Studio not generate the reports folder under build?

Tags: android-studio, android-build, android-lint, android-studio-arctic-fox

I was looking at an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322365/355456) for the error I am getting - "Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.". It suggests looking at the reports folder but the build folder does not have it:
[image]

Do I need to configure Android Studio in a certain way to see the reports folder?

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034, built on November 21, 2021